# PHP cURL over TOR what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, curl, tor

So I'm trying to cURL to an onion site, e.g: facebookcorewwwi.onion
I would have the following code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://facebookcorewwwi.onion/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($html);
```

This gives the following output:
bool(false)

yet this is not what I want as a result, I want the actual page content!
inb4: yes I have the tor browser open

curl_error gives the following error:
Error: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9050: Connection refused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor browser by default uses port 9150 for SOCKS, where the default for the Tor daemon on Linux or the Expert Bundle on Windows is 9050.

If you change to port 9150 you should successfully be able to relay through Tor.

Answer (score 0):

From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) for `curl_exec`:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

If `curl_exec` is returning a boolean of false, an error has occurred. Try fetching the error:

```
$html = curl_exec($curl);
if ( $html === false ) {
   echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
```

Comment: It returns this error: "Error: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9050: Connection refused"
Which is weird as the tor browser is open

Comment: I assume this is a Windows machine?

Comment: At this point, it's not really a curl related question, it's a TOR related question. I'd look at something like this for ideas: http://superuser.com/questions/303251/how-to-check-if-a-socks5-proxy-works Run netstat on windows and ensure the port is listening. Make sure TOR doesn't require authentication (Not quite sure the protocol).